# Inflate layout in ViewPager

Tags: android, view, kotlin

That's my viewpager xml

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

How can I inflate a layout resource in onCreateView?

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

}
```

I tried with something like that

```
val rootView = inflater.inflate(resID, container, false)
return rootView
```

But this showed white activity

Here's the layout that I'm triyng to inflate

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.9" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="444dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline" />
 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: onCreateView is your Fragment Method you have to add design code in your .xml file then bind your .xml with your fragment.

Comment: I've already created the design code, I'm asking how to bind my .xml with my fragment @X-ByteTechnolabspvt.ltd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will inflate the viewpager layout:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?,
                            savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    return inflater?.inflate(R.layout.viewpager, container, false) // provide the name of your layout  
  }
```

If you want to show the XML (you provided) then you need to create a Fragment that contains the XML. You need to create a ViewPagerAdapter for showing the fragment on `viewPager`.

Example:

**your_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.9" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="444dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline" />
 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**YourFragment.kt**

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView

class YourFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container, false)
        return view
    }
}
```

And **ViewPagerAdapter.kt**

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter

class ViewPagerAdapter internal constructor(fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fm) {

    private val COUNT = 3

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment? {
        var fragment: Fragment? = null
        when (position) {
            0 -> fragment = YourFragment()
            1 -> fragment = YourFragment()
            2 -> fragment = YourFragment()
        }

        return fragment
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return COUNT
    }

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
        return " "
    }
}
```

And from your viewpager Fragment use this:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?,
                                savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater?.inflate(R.layout.viewpager, container, false) // provide the name of your layout  
        val viewPager = view.findViewById<ViewPager>(R.id.viewPager)
        if (viewPager != null) {
            val adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
            viewPager.adapter = adapter
        }
        return view
      }
```

Comment: That's exactly what i tried first but it shows blank activity

Comment: ViewPager have any data? Please add a background color for viewpager and check color is showing or not. If color is showing then layout inflate problem is fixed.

Comment: Great. layout successfully inflated. What kind of data you want to show on viewPager?

Comment: The layout is not inflated, it shows viewpager's color, not the new layout's color

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179739/discussion-between-faysal-ahmed-and-filippo).

Answer (score 0):

Design your adapter somewhat like this after populating fragment.

```
private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager)
        {
            super(fragmentManager);
        }
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch(position){
                case 0: return fragment1.newInstance();
                case 1: return fragment2.newInstance();
                case 2: return fragment3.newInstance();
                default: return fragment1.newInstance();
            }

        }
```

And in last set adapter to viewpager like this

```
vPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
```